# Wrong array with while

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I'm sorry for this question, I'm sure is a noob question.

But... I'm not able to manage that and I'm sorry for asking your help.

I have this script:

```
   <?php
       $query = "SELECT logo FROM club";
       $result = $con->query($query);
       while($row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM)){
       print_r($row);
   }
   ?>
```

I'm obtaining this kind of array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => AldwychVertigos.png ) [1] => Array ( [0] => celticnewcastle.png ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Darkwear.png ) [3] => Array ( [0] => InterUltrafox.png ) [4] => Array ( [0] => IrefulXI.png ) [5] => Array ( [0] => KensingtonWest.png ) [6] => Array ( [0] => Vandyke.png ) [7] => Array ( [0] => ZetaUnited.png ) [8] => Array ( [0] => ZigZag.png ) [9] => Array ( [0] => ZionPark.png ) [10] => Array ( [0] => Ignitabulum.png ) [11] => Array ( [0] => AgileVigne.png ) [12] => Array ( [0] => BravaZena.png ) [13] => Array ( [0] => ItalianWarriors.png ) [14] => Array ( [0] => MWM.png ) [15] => Array ( [0] => NavyBlu.png ) [16] => Array ( [0] => SCEsseErre.png ) [17] => Array ( [0] => VoxPopuli.png ) [18] => Array ( [0] => Zanzare.png ) [19] => Array ( [0] => ZebreRoma.png ) [20] => Array ( [0] => AmbrosianaFC.png ) [21] => Array ( [0] => ClubPhoenix.png ) [22] => Array ( [0] => DinamoKangaroo.png ) [23] => Array ( [0] => FioreFC.png ) [24] => Array ( [0] => Kogins.png ) [25] => Array ( [0] => LupoTosco.png ) [26] => Array ( [0] => Sporting.png ) [27] => Array ( [0] => Torino49.png ) [28] => Array ( [0] => Xugia2004.png ) [29] => Array ( [0] => Young00.png ) )
```

How could I obtain an array which directly give me: 
`[0] => AldwychVertigos.png, [1] => celticnewcastle.png`, etc?

Thank you

Comment: Does this make an infinite loop? I'd think `fetch_all` in a `while` would keep going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a single dimension array you need to either use [`fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) instead of `fetch_all` and push the single column into the array, instead of the entire result set, ie:

```
<?php
    $query  = "SELECT logo FROM club";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $array  = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
      $array[] = $row[0];
    }
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use fetch() in while loops, not fetchAll(). fetchAll pulls all the rows at once.

Comment: While you are technically correct, you're assuming he is using `PDO`, the use of the constant `MYSQLI_NUM` and `fetch_all` shows he is using the `MySQLi` extension directly and as such the correct method to call is `fetch_row`.